# Modify array with multiple decimal points and turning seconds into minutes

Tags: ruby

I’m inputting a group of numbers from a text file or a copy/paste into terminal. Example below for copy/paste:

```
2.552789
2.919615
3.542125
4.212462
5.261249
6.320953
```

and on and on. The numbers are all separated by a line, and they all follow this format of `seconds.hundredths of a second`.

I’m inputting the list of numbers into an array and rounding to two decimal places using:

```
while
  input != " "
  array.push 0.0 + input.to_f.round(2)
  input = gets.chomp
end

file_to_open = gets.chomp
array = File.open(file_to_open).readlines.each do |line|
input = file_to_open
while
  input != ''
    array.push 0.0 + input.to_f.round(2)
    input = gets.chomp
  end
```

I’m also having the script select every 4th item out of the array using:

```
module Enumerable
  def every_nth(n)
    (0... self.length).select{ |x| x%n == n-1 }.map { |y| self[y] }
  end
end
```

Lastly, I’m using a block to add a `"0."` in front of each number

```
array = array.map! {|word| "0.#{word}" }
```

When using `print array`, the output is as desired as:

```
0.2.55 0.2.91 0.3.54 0.4.21 0.5.26 0.6.32.
```

When I get to 60 seconds, the list continues in seconds when it should become minutes, for example:

```
0.61.54
0.63.78
```

I’d like anything over 60 seconds to be expressed as `m.ss.hs`, i.e.

```
“1.1.54”
“1.3.78”
```

I could do this with modulo `% 60`, but I’m not sure how to handle this for the entire array. I was playing around with the number before the first decimal point (the minute) being a variable, and adding `1` to the variable if `the seconds number % 60 == 0`, but this wouldn’t help me at `120` seconds because `120 % 60 == 0` as well.

My code works up until 60 seconds, and I’d like it to shift anything over 60 seconds into minutes appropriately. I couldn’t find anything that explains how to modify an array with three decimal places (and not in the standard `h:m:s` format). Any and all assistance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the method to convert a number of seconds in the format you have described above to the format of `minutes.seconds.hundredths`

```
def display_minute(sec)
  round_sec = sec.to_i
  # Get the minute
  m = round_sec / 60
  # Get the remaining seconds
  s = round_sec % 60
  # The hundredth as integer
  h = (sec - round_sec).round(2) * 100
  h = h.to_i
  # Combine result
  [m, s, h].join('.')
end
```

Some results from this method:

```
display_minute(6.320953)
 => "0.6.32" 
display_minute(61.320953)
 => "1.1.32" 
display_minute(121.320953)
 => "2.1.32" 
display_minute(185.320953)
 => "3.5.32"
```

Comment: Thanks this is super helpful! My one question is where do I run this method on all elements of the array? I tried using it but wasn't able to get it to work. Do I run it on input? On Output? Or After input but before output (like would I have to use map! and then run the method (ie array = array.map! {|word| #{word}.display_minute}?

Comment: Yes, after you read input from file and store it in an array, you can apply this method to each element in array and get an output array in your desired format. The right syntax is:
`output_array = array.map { |word| display_minute(word) }`

Answer (score 0):

As you said,

> I was playing around with the number before the first decimal point (the minute) being a variable and adding 1 to the variable if the seconds number % 60 == 0, but this wouldn’t help me at 120 seconds because 120 % 60 == 0 as well.

You can try this.

> if seconds%60>=0 and seconds/60>=1, you can add the make the minute as
>   seconds/60 and seconds as seconds%60.